# How to inject a dependency into a base class if child doesn't know it?

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection

I have an abstract base class `Command` that depends on `ICommandLogger` interface:

```
public abstract class Command
{
    public Command(ICommandLogger cmdLogger) { /* ... */ }
}
```

And now all the inheritors are look like:

```
public class ConcreteCommand : Command
{
     public ConcreteCommand(CommandLoggersNamespace.ICommandLogger cmdLogger)
         : base(cmdLogger)
     {
     }
}
```

I don't like they are forced to know about `ICommandLogger` (which they do not use).

How to get around of this? Or what are the reasons for complete redesign?

Comment: Why is it an issue that a command knows about an abstract ICommandLogger ... ?

Comment: You *could* fall back to Property Injection. But constructor injection is more clear, and therefore, the better choice IMHO.

Comment: But your `ConcreteCommand` *does* know about the logger. It's just that the behaviour is inherited.

Comment: It's just a matter of perception. Would it sound strange to you that a driver knows about their vehicle's dependency on fuel even though they themselves are not using it?

Comment: @Jon Every object you create is dependant on OS and even on electrons interaction, but you don't injecting them into each class constructor, right?

Comment: I 'm not going to go into electrons (no idea why you even brought it up), but since you mentioned the OS: the dependency on the OS is satisfied through DLLs. The fact that this dependency is hidden behind a service locator is a design decision. You decided to design your class to use constructor injection instead of service location, so your example is comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: @Jon Service Locator! Thank you!

Comment: Don't use Service Locator. That's a [bad idea](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Comment: @Steven After your answer I threw this idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a problem in your design that causing you all this trouble. First of all, logging is a [cross-cutting concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) and you should prevent polluting classes with that. Second, if you let the base class implement logging, what is the next cross-cutting concern that will be added on the logger base class. The second you start adding another cross-cutting concern, the base class will violate the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Your base class will eventually grow to a big unmanageable class with lots of dependencies, and lot's of reasons to change.

Instead, try adding logging as a decorator. Your design however, prevents you from effectively doing that, since you will probably have dozens of concrete commands and they would all need their own decorator. But the core problem with your design is that you mix data and behavior. Let the command be nothing more than a class containing some data (DTO) and extra the commands logic into its own class; let's call that the *command handler*.

On top of that, let command handlers implement this interface:

```cs
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

This will look like this:

```cs
public class MoveCustomerCommand
{
    public Guid CustomerId;
    public Address NewAddress;
}

public class MoveCustomerCommmandHandler : ICommandHandler<MoveCustomerCommand>
{
    public void Handle(MoveCustomerCommand command)
    {
        // behavior here.
    }
}
```

What's interesting about this design is that since all business logic is now hidden behind one [narrow interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), and this interface is generic, it becomes very easy to [extend the behavior of the system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) by wrapping handlers with decorators. For instance a logging decorator:

```cs
public class LoggingCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand> 
    : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> decoratee;

    public LoggingCommandHandlerDecorator(
        ICommandHandler<TCommand> decoratee, ILog log)
    {
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
        this.log = log;
    }

    public void Handle(TCommand command)
    {
        this.log.Log("Executing " + typeof(TCommand).Name + ": " +
            JsonConvert.Serialize(command));

        try
        {
            this.decoratee.Handle(command);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.log.Log(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Since this `LoggingCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand>` is generic, it can be wrapped around any `ICommandHandler<TCommand>`. This allows you to let consumers take a dependency on some `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` (such as `ICommandHandler<MoveCustomerCommand>`) and you can add crosscutting concerns to all business logic without changing a single line of code.

This will in most cases remove the need to use a base class completely.

You can read more about this type of design [here](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91).

Comment: Very deep insight into design's real problems. Thank you!

Comment: You might also be interested in [this related Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829818/refactoring-procedural-wcf-service).

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing dependency injection via the constructor, there's no way around this. An alternative is dependency injection via property setters. Personally, I prefer the constructor method, because to me, that communicates that this class **requires** this dependency whereas a property-injected dependency communicates an optional dependency.

If you go the constructor route, and your base class takes a lot of dependencies, you can alleviate some of the pain by [creating an aggregate service](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) so that the base only needs one parameter injected instead of many.

Comment: +1 for mentioning required dependencies vs optional dependencies.

Comment: So, If dependency is not optional (`Command` really needs logger) the pain is not avoidable you mean?

Comment: It's not avoidable if you're using inheritance to model your behavior. Since constructors are not inherited in C#, you are forced to add constructor chains to subclasses. A more "radical" approach would be to use composition instead of inheritance. This is why I prefer to use interfaces when possible. For example, you might define `ICommand` and then `ConcreteCommand` can implement that but not inherit from `Command`.

Answer (score 1):

If they don't use the command logger you may try to not set any at all, like this:

```
public ConcreteCommand()
    : base(null)
{
}
```

If this does not work (throws an `Exception`) you may try to implement a [phony](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phony) command logger and instantiated that one:

```
public ConcreteCommand()
    : base(new MyPhonyCommandLogger())
{
}
```

If you don't want those phony instances around, have a single instance statically available:

```
public ConcreteCommand()
    : base(MyPhonyCommandLogger.Instance)
{
}
```

Comment: I think the OP's point was that the inheritors do not use the logger, but the base-class **does**.

Comment: The logger is a dependency of the base class. In the absence of explicit guarantees how is the child class going to know if the dependency will be used or not?

Answer (score 1):

Well another way of looking at it is that the `ConcreteComand` class *does* have a dependency on `ICommandLogger`. It inherited it when it derived from Command.

- Therefore there is no way around what you are doing that makes sense other than for `ConcreteCommand` to accept the dependency on behalf of its base class - think about it not in terms of "`ConcreteCommand` has a `Command`" but more like "`ConcreteCommand` *is* a `Command`"
- Think about how you'd handle wanting to override the base class logging behaviour if you somehow were able to get he base class dependency on `ICommandLogger` to somehow "sneak past" the construction of `ConcreteCommand`...
- If you want to be able to provide "base like" functionality (`base.Log("foo")`), etc) and you absolutely do not want `ConcreteComand` to know about `ICommandLogger`, then you can always switch to "has a" type scenario - whereby `Command` is just a member variable of `ConcreteCommand` (a silly reason approach in this case IMHO!)

Answer (score 0):

> I don't like they are forced to know about ICommandLogger (which they
>   do not use).

Well they do; unless you instantiate an object of type `ICommandLogger` in the abstract class and provide a parameterless constructor, you're currently forcing inheritors to know about it.

Comment: No, they don't use it. By "usage" I mean calling it's members. What do you mean by "usage"?